# Test private APIs on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, device, iphone-privateapi

I am a newbie to iOS development. I have to develop an app that uses private APIs and I understand the restrictions posed by the App Store for such apps. I just want to know if I can slap the app on a phone to test.. I don't want to distribute the app anyway. Please advise..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes as long as your device is registered (on the provisioning page) and marked "use for development." you can test on your device without any kind of interference from apple.